Create a dynamic column based on the other column
I'm creating a Data Engineer model in Snowflake where I need to calculate the new column (Allocation) with a value of 1 till the projection has negative values, the default value will be 0
TABLE



Supply
Demand
Week_Start_Date
Proj
Allocation




1500
500
15-04-2024
1000
1


0
500
22-04-2024
500
1


0
500
29-04-2024
0
1


0
500
06-05-2024
-500
1


500
500
20-05-2024
-500
1


0
500
03-06-2024
1000
1


0
500
10-06-2024
-1500
1


0
500
17-06-2024
-2000
1


10000
500
24-06-2024
7500
0


0
500
01-07-2024
7000
0


0
500
08-07-2024
6500
0




One approach, using window functions:
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
           SUM(CASE WHEN Proj < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER () AS total_cnt,
           SUM(CASE WHEN Proj < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY Week_Start_Date) AS cnt
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT Supply, Demand, Week_Start_Date, Proj,
       CASE WHEN cnt = total_cnt AND Proj > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Allocation
FROM cte
ORDER BY Week_Start_Date;

Another more old school approach, using a correlated subquery:
SELECT Supply, Demand, Week_Start_Date, Proj,
       CASE WHEN Proj > 0 AND
            NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM yourTable t2
                WHERE t2.Week_Start_Date > t1.Week_Start_Date AND t2.Proj < 0
            )
            THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Allocation
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY Week_Start_Date;

